# Using VB 2010 with MS SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

I am sure I am no the only person asking this, I have looked on the internet where there are a lot of similar questions but not a clear answer.

I think my question is simple but the answer is not (isn't it always the case!)

I want to design a  simple 1 form vb 2010 application that links to a sql server 2008 database and return the table customers. Sounds simple.

I want to use a gridview which I have working fine but I also want to use the binding navigater( a bad name for what is a record navigator!). This I cant get to grips with at all.

Its seem I need a table adapter and a binding source. It just seems to get very messym.

Is there a simple explanation out there anywhere.

Secondly, if it was a ms access database, a excel file or even a ms sql3.5, I could create a datasource and then use the properties field to tie it all together, why cant I do this with sql server 2008? why do I need to hardcode it?.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Visual Studio is not PowerBuilder.

Answer (score 0):

Working with dataSources (of any sort) in Visual Studio is incredibly easy.  Start up VS, create a new project, then create a DataSource using the Add Data Source Wizard.  Once you get the data source set up and connected to your source data, then just drag and drop the data source from the Data Sources tab onto the form.  Voila!  Your datagridview, binding navigator, and everything else you need is automatically added and configured for you.

Comment: While this works, I would suggest you figure out how to do this with code before using the wizard so you actually understand what the heck is going on.

Comment: @Jack Marchetti, good idea, but this may also help him get the idea if he looks at the auto-generated code/designer after.